# On the dimension of an abstract simplicial complex built from minimal vertex covers of a finite simple graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, simplicial-complex, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $G$ be a finite simple graph on a vertex set $\{x_1,...,x_n\}.$  Let us call a [vertex cover](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#:%7E:text=In%20the%20mathematical%20discipline%20of,every%20edge%20of%20the%20graph.) of $G$ to be minimal if none of its proper subset is a vertex cover. Let $C_1,...,C_h$ be the collection of all minimal vertex covers of $G$.

Let $\Delta$ be the [abstract simplicial complex](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) on the vertex set
$V:=\{i: 1\le i\le n; \{x_i\} \text{ is not a minimal vertex cover} \}$ and the faces of $\Delta$ are the proper subsets of $C_i$ s.

My question is:

> Can we find the  dimension of $\Delta$ in terms of some invariant of $G$?

I feel that $\dim \Delta =\min_{i} |C_i| -1$, but I'm not sure.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The faces of $\Delta$ are the proper subsets of the $C_i$. The dimension of $\Delta$ is the dimension of a face with maximal possible number of vertices. Such a face is obtained by choosing $C_j$ that has maximal cardinality among the $C_i$ and then removing one element $x\in C_j$ to obtain $F=C_j\setminus\{x\}$.

Hence
$$
\dim\Delta = \dim F = |F|-1 = |C_j|-2 = \max_{i=1,\dots,h} |C_i| - 2.
$$